# Which Charizard Mega Evolution is better for sweeping?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm currently breeding a Charizard for perfect IVs for my Competitive Pokemon ORAS team so that he can be a sweeper. I researched which mega evolution for Charizard is better and all that came up was opinions, so I decided to come here to ask for fact based reasoning on which mega evolution is best for a Charizard Sweeper.

This is my current SINGLE BATTLE Team:

Gengar @(Unknown) Nature: Modest

Sludge Bomb
Thunderbolt
Focus Blast
Shadow Ball

Blaziken @(Unknown) Nature: Unknown

Protect
Bulk Up
Baton Pass
Toxic

Charizard @(Charizardite X/Y) Nature: Unknown

N/A

Comment: They can't really be compared, they're very different. One deals physical damage, the other special. One is Fire/Dragon, the other Fire/Flying. One has Drought, the other does not. There are too many differences and classing one as "better" depends on what the rest of your team needs and what you expect to be facing, as well as whether it's a single, double, triple, or rotation battle.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer There, I edited it to specify my answer for you.

Comment: I didn't mean that was enough to answer the question, neither is better than the other. And since it seems you're using Speed Boost Blaziken, you don't seem to be playing by the standard rules, so that might be worth noting. I still suggest a teambuilding forum instead of Arqade.

Comment: Baton Pass can work on Blaziken, but the other moves don't work that well. Give it Flare Blitz and High Jump Kick over Bulk Up and Toxic. Attack until you're forced out, then baton pass your boosts to something else.

Comment: Your entire team is weak to mold breaker excadrill right now, by the way.

Comment: @Pyritie Yeah, I don't think this'll be my final team right now, I just came up with something so that the other guy wouldn't get mad at me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a bulky type would be better in your team, and a bulky charizard X is one of the most terryfing threats in the current OU metagame. As set, I'd run the following:

```
Charizard-Mega-X @ Charizardite X  
Ability: Tough Claws  
EVs: 248 HP / 252 Atk / 8 SpD  
Adamant Nature  
- Earthquake  
- Dragon Claw  
- Roost  
- Flare Blitz
```

However, if you really want a sweeper, you should run a Mega Charizard X since you already have a special sweeper with that gengar. As set, I'd run the following:

```
Charizard-Mega-X @ Charizardite X  
Ability: Tough Claws  
EVs: 4 HP / 252 Atk / 252 Spe  
Adamant Nature  
- Earthquake  
- Dragon Claw/Outrage
- Flare Blitz  
- Dragon Dance/Overheat
```

Little note: I would not run blaziken like that. It's way too fragile for that. If you really want a baton passer which can pass atk and speed, try [scolipede](http://www.smogon.com/dex/xy/pokemon/scolipede/).